# Dependent Select in Formtastic 2.1.x w/ Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I've done some digging here and there doesn't seem to be a universal (simple) answer to this, so I wanted to check:

What's the current best practice for creating dynamic/dependent select options in a form being generated with Formtastic 2.1.x?

In other words - how best to have the `<option>` list for a `<select>` change depending on the value of a different field (i.e - pick a country first, then see a list of states from only that country)

There's a gem I found out there called [dependent-select](https://github.com/topsail/dependent-select) which appeared to do *exactly* what I'm looking for, all nicely wrapped up and packaged -- but development appears to have stopped a year ago and it's only for Formtastic 1.2. (and when this happens it usually means that I'm missing something ;)

[Railscasts #88 (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) discusses this in the context of a regular form, but I was curious if there's a  way to do this using Formtastic....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on this same problem. I did run across this gist: https://gist.github.com/3077281. I'm going to attempt to work a solution using it.  Might help you as well.

Comment: Thanks Jake.  I ended up following along with the Railcasts #88 solution I linked to above and manually implemented basically the same setup.  I was hoping there was something pre-made to do this, but if you come up with something let me know!